# Vaadin 23 WebSockets iPhone updates with delays

Tags: iphone, websocket, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I noticed a strange behavior - sometimes (not always) on my iPhone I click a button with asynchronous logic(`@Push`), but nothing happens. Then I press another button on the same screen and can see that the response for the first button comes, but now nothing happens for the second button. And so on… I always need to press the next button to complete the action called by the previous one… What could be causing this?

I do not see any issues in NGINX/Tomcat logs, I see requests in the access logs. Also, on my computer, everything is working fine. This issue is only appears on my iPhone. If I refresh the page - everything starts working properly.

**UPDATED**

In application logs I see the following DEBUG message:

```
2022-11-13 05:38:23.147 DEBUG 1545984 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] com.vaadin.flow.server.StaticFileServer  : failed to read jar file contents

java.io.IOException: Can not read scheme 'war' for resource jar:war:file:/srv/..../ui-0.0.1.jar*/BOOT-INF/lib/flow-push-23.2.6.jar!/META-INF/resources/VAADIN/static/push/vaadinPush-min.js and will determine this as not a folder
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.StaticFileServer.getFileSystem(StaticFileServer.java:173) ~[flow-server-23.2.6.jar!/:23.2.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.StaticFileServer.resourceIsDirectory(StaticFileServer.java:116) ~[flow-server-23.2.6.jar!/:23.2.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.StaticFileServer.serveStaticResource(StaticFileServer.java:277) ~[flow-server-23.2.6.jar!/:23.2.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.serveStaticOrWebJarRequest(VaadinServlet.java:401) ~[flow-server-23.2.6.jar!/:23.2.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:356) ~[flow-server-23.2.6.jar!/:23.2.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106) ~[vaadin-spring-23.2.6.jar!/:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
```

Should I be worried about such a message?

and one more exception:

```
2022-11-13 05:42:12.308 DEBUG 1545984 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint  : Problem in web socket session

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:157) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:60) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:59) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

What may be wrong with my setup? Please advise where to look in order to fix this.

Comment: Are the two errors only shown with iPhone connections, or also with desktop browser connections?

Comment: I think mostly with iPhone... it's really hard to say

Comment: The same behavior I may emulate when add `value = PushMode.DISABLED` to the `@PUSH` annotation and try to invoke some logic which relies on web-sockets in my application