# Vaadin 23 @Push(transport = Transport.WEBSOCKET_XHR) ping socket

Tags: websocket, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Please correct me if I'm wrong that `Transport.WEBSOCKET_XHR` means that browser asks server via `XmlHttpRequest` (AJAX) and server responds to the browser via websocket.

So, with `Transport.WEBSOCKET_XHR`, is there any out-of-the-box functionality available in Vaadin to check if a web socket is still alive before an XHR request, like (ping pong)? If there is no such functionality, how can I implement it myself?

If no, do we have such validation for pure full-duplex websocket implementation with  `Transport.WEBSOCKET`? Will Vaadin effectively detect dead websocket on the initial call to server with `Transport.WEBSOCKET`?

Comment: Do you have issues with the Push?

Comment: As Vaadin uses Atmosphere I would say this is handled by Atmosphere and also can be probably configured there.

Comment: Yes, the following issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74418180/vaadin-23-websockets-iphone-updates-with-delays  On flaky internet connection XHR works but looks like do not receive  a web-sockets response.

Comment: looks like strategy with `Transport.WEBSOCKET_XHR` don't understand that web-socket connection is not alive.. maybe because of absence of ping-pong health check..